# How to type return type to be a promise only if receiving function also returns a promise?

Tags: typescript, async-await, typescript-generics

I'm making this silly function that will make a try/catch for any function and return it as a tuple with data and error

```
export type CatchReturn<T> = [data: T | undefined, error: unknown | undefined];

export const tcatch = <T>(
  tryFunc: (() => T) | (() => Promise<T>)
) => {
  try {
    const res = tryFunc();
    if (res instanceof Promise) {
      return res
        .then<CatchReturn<T>>((r) => [r, undefined])
        .catch<CatchReturn<T>>((e) => [undefined, e]);
    } else {
      return [res, undefined] as CatchReturn<T>;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return [undefined, e] as CatchReturn<T>;
  }
};
```

The function works as expected, but what I'm not able to do is correctly type the return type.

At the moment, the return type is `CatchReturn<T> | Promise<CatchReturn<T>>` but I wanted the return type to only be `CatchReturn<T>` if `tryFunc: (() => T)` and `Promise<CatchReturn<T>>` only if `tryFunc: (() => Promise<T>)`.

So for example:

How it's working at the moment

```
const syncRes = tcatch(() => {}) // return type is CatchReturn<T> | Promise<CatchReturn<T>>
const asyncRes = tcatch(async () => {}) // return type is CatchReturn<T> | Promise<CatchReturn<T>>
```

How I expect it to work

```
const syncRes = tcatch(() => {}) // return type should be CatchReturn<T>
const asyncRes = tcatch(async () => {}) // return type should be Promise<CatchReturn<T>>
```

I tried using conditional types in the return type, but always got errors and I'm not 100% sure if this is even possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a job for function overloads. You simply declare one function signature for promises, and another for other functions. Then your implementation returns a union of both:

```
// signatures
export function tcatch<T>(tryFunc: () => Promise<T>): Promise<CatchReturn<T>>
export function tcatch<T>(tryFunc: () => T): CatchReturn<T>

// implementation
export function tcatch<T>(
  tryFunc: (() => T) | (() => Promise<T>)
): CatchReturn<T> | Promise<CatchReturn<T>> {
  //...
}
```

Which seems to work as you expect:

```
const syncRes = tcatch(() => {}) // CatchReturn<void>
const asyncRes = tcatch(async () => {}) // Promise<CatchReturn<void>>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.6.2&ssl=24&ssc=70&pln=23&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCBDGBjAFgJWBgFcoA7AHgBUA+OAXjgG0ATLDALjirgB85iZFsABmASzLAWAGjjAoUaF0EBrMhADuZPgKGiJUgLoBuALAAoC1fOhIsOCMHYYYiNpxY81GgAoYURAAxJy4fAEoGOgAFRQBbMQBnYG8wrhiIeKSKTBwCIlJKWhoLW2h4RzJnV3dsT1xvPwDgytCI+joqVPQ6whJyb2tS+wqqtwRa3Ib-IJC4H3DI7gj+ebbouMTk2jCunLxegu8ddMzkvby+wpo6AG8LOAQAuDvzB4fsNwT4KGAEhkeZpVwmZXm8xCI5j8-hIvhhKsAIBCTpsIi83m8fpc4FD7ui3gA6GC4YCUc4HfpFeZQNbMKCyQTCcSSFiGMK4vFwfETLxk-IU67zYA0pgM-TM2TAVkg9EAXzkABsks92Ri+domFD6XomUZpW8Zbi5dzcHMhcrQQ9MQVmKKdTI5CZDRYZSCLB8yF84AlEJVCH9GB5cqtFjcZREAPTh7q5cmUABuEDELGK5ndnow3t9v3+gbwPgzPuwcxpoYjUeRWV5lwoCaT1yAA)

Answer (score 0):

Not so elegant way, but...

```
export type CatchReturn<T> = [data: T | undefined, error: unknown | undefined];

type MaybeMappedPromise<F extends () => unknown> = ReturnType<F> extends Promise<infer T> ? Promise<CatchReturn<T>> : CatchReturn<ReturnType<F>>

function tcatch<T extends unknown, F extends (() => T) | (() => Promise<T>)>(
  tryFunc: F
): MaybeMappedPromise<F> {
  try {
    const res = tryFunc();
    if (res instanceof Promise) {
      return res
        .then<CatchReturn<T>>((r) => [r, undefined])
        .catch<CatchReturn<T>>((e) => [undefined, e]) as MaybeMappedPromise<F>;
    } else {
      return [res, undefined] as MaybeMappedPromise<F>;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    return [undefined, e] as MaybeMappedPromise<F>;
  }
}

const syncRes = tcatch(() => {}) // return type should be CatchReturn<T>
const asyncRes = tcatch(async () => {}) // return type should be Promise<CatchReturn<T>>
```